# Rename command mistake, files do not show anymore in windows network drives

Tags: linux, files, rename

I made a mistake with rename command

```
find . -type f -exec rename 's/[^A-Za-z0-9._]//g' {} +
```

After that the files are not under their folders as they used to be and every file has . in front of them. Now my customers can not see the files. Once I remove the . then they can see the files.

How can I remove . from the files.
Like this:

```
.finacialyear2008half.doc
```

to

```
finacialyear2008half.doc
```

Please help me! I need a fast fix.

Comment: The next time use `rename -n` for a dry-run. It just prints how it would rename your files without doing anything to them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`find . -type f -exec  rename 's/\.//' '{}' \;`

Think about -n parameter of rename : it just display what it will do after you remove it !

Comment: find . -type f -exec rename 's/\.//'
find: missing argument to `-exec'

Comment: Sorry : I edit my entry

Comment: Can't rename ./.maksuvladtabelina.xlsx /.maksuvladtabelina.xlsx: Invalid cross-device link <- Any ideas?

Comment: OK : change the find . to your absolute path !

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using bash you can loop through the files replacing first occurrences of `/.` with `/` in the filenames of all files in the current folder.

```
for filename in $(find . -maxdepth 1 -type f)
do
  mv -v $filename ${filename/\/.//}
done
```

This assumes that you don't need to recursively rename files, and will only work in current directory (`-maxdepth 1`).

Disclaimer: always backup your files or at least try with a bunch of test files before performing any actions on your data.